# How to enable backlog on Jira Kanban project

Tags: jira, kanban, backlog

I created a new kanban project on Jira but no kanban backlog displays. How do I enable this feature on Jira?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Configure your board

[image]

Step 2: Drop and drag backlog status to kanban backlog

[image]

You will notice backlog is activated

[image]

Step 3:Go back to board. Now your kanban project has a kanban backlog

[image]